# Google Experiments breaking Account Signup

Tags: google-analytics, ab-experiment

We have an A/B test with Google Experiments on our homepage - http://www.theirishstore.com/

However, if you try going to the account page, and then try to create a new account by clicking on the link, the Experiment code redirects you to: https://www.theirishstore.com/customer/account/create/?utm_expid=37348836-3.Pt5YYdmpRwGED_uioyf7Ew.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theirishstore.com%2Fcustomer%2Faccount%2Flogin%2F

Does anyone have a solution for stopping Google Experiment code from interfering on pages that are NOT the homepage?

Comment: What did you do to enable Google Experiments?

Comment: Hi Alan, I put the javascript given by google on what I thought was the homepage only. But just checking, my regexp was wrong, and it was on the Account page. PEBKAC. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a bit of PEBKAC - I had the google javascript on the create new account pages, due to a dodgy regexp.